# How to highlight some calendar dates based on server data in calendar view

Tags: android, android-calendar

I am using "https://github.com/npanigrahy/Custom-Calendar-View" library to work with custom calendar.Now my problem is I will get absent dates of month from server and I have to change color of text of those dates in calendar. how it is possible to do using this library. Also I want to make use of its next and previous button but not able to do so.

Answer (score 0):

The library is using a day decorator function.

//adding calendar day decorators

```
List decorators = new ArrayList<>();
decorators.add(new ColorDecorator());
calendarView.setDecorators(decorators);
calendarView.refreshCalendar(currentCalendar);
```

Go through the documentation you will surely get something to work with.

Comment: I am asking about using previous and next button with changing date color